# Can the package XML be accessed from the preflight method?

Tags: xml

In the package installation script, preflight method, is there a way to access the package's XML? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The preflight method has two parameters, and you can, for example, obtain the current version being installed with:

```
function preflight($type, $parent) {
    $version = (string) $parent->getManifest()->version;
}
```